# How do I open .bov files that are on my university's cluster using python commands? The program runs on the cluster and creates .bov files

Tags: python, sbatch

The program is separate. Once it runs, I get the `.bov` files in  another directory I call output.

Then I type, module load `allpy`
then, python
and then any bit of python code I want. But I don't know how to open these `.bov` files.

Comment: add your code..